# Peer review for a cryptographic key exchange

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, aes, diffie-hellman

I have been playing around with Bouncy Castle (java) for the last few days, and I've reached the point where I believe I can securely exchange secret keys with a Diffie-Hellman exchange.

Having read many posts underlining the difficulty of properly implementing a cryptographic exchange, I would like your honest opinion on my work.
All the underlying cipher operations are based on Bouncy Castle and may therefore be deemed reliable.

```
    String message = "Hello World";

    AESCipher aes_client = new AESCipher(256);
    RSACipher rsa_server = new RSACipher(2048);

    // (Public key sent over the wire)
    RSACipher rsa_client = new RSACipher(rsa_server.getPublicKey().getModulus(),
                                         rsa_server.getPublicKey().getExponent());

    // The client encodes his AES key with the RSA public key:
    byte[] aes_key = rsa_client.encode(aes_client.getKeyBytes());
    byte[] aes_iv = rsa_client.encode(aes_client.getInitializationVector());

    // (Data sent back over the wire)
    byte[] decoded_aes_key = rsa_server.decode(aes_key);
    byte[] decoded_aes_iv = rsa_server.decode(aes_iv);

    // The server creates an AES server which uses the client key:
    AESCipher aes_server = new AESCipher(decoded_aes_key, decoded_aes_iv);

    byte[] encoded_message = aes_client.encode(message.getBytes());
    byte[] decoded_message = aes_server.decode(encoded_message);

    System.out.println(new String(decoded_message));
```

Can this exchange be considered safe? Should I be sticking with SSL Sockets, eventhough it'd hurt to thrash my hard work?
Thanks in advance for your input!

(By the way, my Bouncy-Castle-Wrapping-Library is totally open-source, so just let me know if you want the repository's URL.)

Comment: Might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know about this website. Thanks for the info, I'll take my question over there.

Comment: @Executifs, how do you know fight the man in the middle issue. You need some root cert to authenticate the server public key. or the client has the public key already installed?

Comment: None of the above : MITM hasn't been identified as a threat for my application. Passive wiretapping is the only target here. Pre-installing the public key is a viable option, though.

Comment: @Executifs, if you can ensure very trusted connection (no DNS attacks?), you should be ok. Although the easier way to exchange sym. key is just a SSL socket (https usually) and exchange, proceed w/ AES/RCx/whatever

Comment: @bestsss Thank you very much for your input. I'll look into the Station-to-Station Protocol just in case.

Comment: How can you call this Diffie-Hellman when it is actually RSA?

Comment: There might be padding issued with the way you use RSA.

Comment: I would like to see the repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(There is no Diffie-Hellman in your protocol, only RSA and symmetric encryption.)

A first basic remark is that your protocol is vulnerable to active attacks. "Man-in-the-middle" is a classic (the attacker intercepts the public key, replacing it with his own). Also, you only have symmetric encryption, but no MAC. Let's assume that your attack model is about passive attackers only; most of the time, this is, to say the least, a very bold assumption. Actually, I have trouble imagining a situation where this would apply: an eavesdropper who can look at the transmitted bytes but incapable of sending his own messages. Unless you run the whole thing within an authenticated tunnel with integrity checks (SSL has a mode for that, but this kind of defeat the point).

You are encrypting the IV, which is not needed (the IV is not the key, otherwise it would be called a "key", not an IV). What you need from an IV is to be randomly generated for each encrypted message. Assuming that you use CBC mode, it is acceptable that the last encrypted block from a message is used as IV for the next message. It would be deadly, however, to reuse an IV for two distinct messages with the same symmetric encryption key. Since Bouncy Castle does not have any class named `AESCipher`, your sample code does not tell us whether you are using AES with a proper chaining mode and correct IV management. Note also that reusing the last encrypted block from the previous message works only as long as messages are sent sequentially, and no message is lost. A more robust solution is to:

1. select a new random IV (through a cryptographically strong RNG, e.g. `java.security.SecureRandom`) for each message;
2. send the concatenation of the IV, and the encrypted data, as encoded message.

This allows the receiver to recover the IV (as first message block) and then process the message regardless of whether previous messages were sent and received. There again, an active attacker may wreak havoc in that scheme, if only through simple "replay attacks" (the attacker sends a copy of a previously sent message).

As a side note, `String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])` use the platform default encoding, which may differ between the client and the server. You would be better off using an explicit charset, e.g. UTF-8: `message.getBytes("UTF-8")` and `new String(decoded_message, "UTF-8")`.

Generically speaking, security and hubris do not mix well. Be prepared to ditch your code. The main reason why you really should use standard protocols such as SSL/TLS is that security cannot be proven. What would you tell to someone (e.g. your boss) asking you what makes you think that the protocol is secure ? "Some guy on Stack Overflow told me so" ?

Comment: I'd assume the OP doesn't transfer strings but byte[] and getBytes() is only for the test case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable advice. I am indeed using CBC mode, but I didn't know about not reusing IVs. This will be fixed right away. Also, you've convinced me to give up on using my code in a production environment. I am, though, adamant on getting to the bottom of this, so I guess I'll look for knowledgeable people willing to give me advice on the whole codebase. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would just point out that an IV is not normally encrypted. I guess there's no harm in it, but it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm always happy to learn something. Thanks for the additional information.